Why did Evelyn place a soda cap on Lee’s gravestone?
Evelyn left Marcus and the baby at the foundry and visited Lee’s gravestone just to place a soda cap on top of it:

Why did Evelyn place a soda cap on Lee’s gravestone?

Leaving things on gravestones is a general cultural practice.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitation_stones
